# Read Kafka Topic from beginning

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, yaml, kafka-topic

I have a spring boot application, that keeps reading all messages from a specific topic.
My problem is that I have an issue that when the application restarts, it needs to read all the messages from the topic again.
I thought these two options combined would do it, but it is not working:

- resetOffsets: true
- startOffset: earliest

Here is my method;

```
 @StreamListener(myTopic)
 public void handle(@Payload Input input) {
    /** Do other stuff not related **/
 }
```

Here is my application.yaml

```
spring:
  cloud.stream:
    bindings:
      myTopic:
        destination: TOPIC
        content-type: application/**avro
        group: group-topic
        concurrency: 1
        resetOffsets: true
        startOffset: earliest
```

Comment: You need to change the consumer group (configuration `group`) to be able to read from beginning. Otherwise the two options resetOffset and startingOffset will not have any impact.

Comment: I couldnt understand what I have to change. Could you detail a little more? Sorry, I'm new at Kafka.

Comment: Hi @Victor no problem. Have added more details in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `group` within your application.yaml to a new and unique group name (see below example where I set the consumer group to *new-consumer-group-id*:

```sh
spring:
  cloud.stream:
    bindings:
      myTopic:
        destination: TOPIC
        content-type: application/**avro
        group: new-consumer-group-id
        concurrency: 1
        resetOffsets: true
        startOffset: earliest
```

If you keep on using the same ConsumerGroup, the configurations `resetOffset` and `startingOffset` will not have any impact.

As an alternative, you could reset the offsets for each consumer group using the command line tool `kafka-consumer-groups.sh`. A template is shown below:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
 --execute --reset-offsets \
 --group groupA\
 --topic topicC \
 --partition 0 \
 --to-offset <insert number>
```

Comment: So in this case, every time my application starts it needs to have a different consumer group? Like, adding a timestamp at the end of the name defined in the yaml?

Comment: yes, that would be a solution. Otherwise you can make use of a command line tool that comes with Kafka. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi @mike, yes, this answered. Thanks a lot.